# iOS: How to handle a released delegate

Tags: ios, delegates

I have a object that serves as a connection layer between my view controller and my webservice. This object takes a delegate and informs that delegate whenever data is returned from the server. I am running into a problem where the delegate gets dealloc'd while an http request is running. When the request returns, my object attempts to call a method on the delegate and the app crashes.

What is the best way to handle this. I have read in several places that you should not retain your delegates because very frequently they are retaining the object too, resulting in a cyclic dependence. So if I can't retain my delegate, how do I check if it has been dealloc'd before I call methods on it?

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSObject<ServerConnectionDelegate>* delegate;
```

Comment: Perhaps using `retainCount`? Are you using ARC?

Comment: @Darksky, **never** use retain count :)

Comment: @Darksky, even if that were a good idea, you can't call `retainCount` because it results in the exact same error (I've tried).

Comment: @Darksky http://whentouseretaincount.com

Comment: Are you using ARC? If you are, weak instead of assign would be way better because weak properties get set to nil when the assigned object is deallocated. Messages sent to nil return nil = no crash, and plus you can check for nil easily first if you want to do something else.

Comment: Relax everyone :) Yes never use `retainCount`. But in his case, he can use it to debug, or at least have an idea how "unbalanced" his allocs/releases are.

Comment: @Darksky I'm not trying to debug the problem. I know exactly what the problem is, so no its not useful. In the end I re-architected the object to use a standard delegation model in which the delegate must remove itself as a delegate before being destroyed. See Vladimir's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you should use delegate pattern if life-time of the delegate is longer than lifetime of worker object. (sorry not sure about correct term here).

You have several options how to fix that:

- As a workaround you can set connection delegate to nil in your object's dealloc method.
- If data is required (may be for some later usage) you can use NSNotification to inform delegate for any connection events instead of delegate pattern.
- As Jack suggested in his comment you can make your delegate a weak property of connection - that will probably be the best solution if your project is using ARC

Comment: Is there some equivalent for a weak property when you aren't using ARC?

Comment: Check this article http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-07-16-zeroing-weak-references-in-objective-c.html may be it will help.

Comment: Thank you for the three options! I never wondered about weak vs assign before now!

Answer (score 0):

You should cancel any running request and set it's delegate to nil in dealloc method.

```
- (void)dealloc
{
   [yourWebServiceRequest cancelRequestAndClearDelegate]; 
   [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Yea I was considering this, but I currently don't hold a reference to the object. I CAN, but I was trying to avoid it.

Comment: Why you want to avoid it ? It is general pattern.

Comment: This also introduces the problem that you now have an external dependency wherein every single object that ever wishes to become the delegate of the connection marshaller object must implement dealloc and include that method call. Often with network marshaling, this could potentially be a very large number of classes (ie every view controller, data processing, etc etc)

Comment: @MSK see Jack Lawrence's comment. This is exactly right, I don't want to have to fix this everywhere. I want to fix it in the class itself. The only reason this is an issue is because its asynchronous.

Comment: so what is the recommended way for non ARC projects ?